# Read and write to file before task is complete using cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, stdout, read-write

Consider, I am using the command

```
C:\>ping www.google.com 1>a.txt 2>&1 | type a.txt
```

It works well as by default windows sends 4 packets, the task ends and then the file content is displayed.
But when I use

```
C:\>ping www.google.com -t 1>a.txt 2>&1 | type a.txt
```

Here the task isn't complete as I have used the `-t` switch. How can I display the file contents as it is being written in the file.
I don't want to use `tee` from  `GnuWin32 CoreUtils`

Comment: if you can use powershell : `ping -t google.fr | tee -FilePath c:\temp\ping.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `tee` from the `GnuWin32 CoreUtils`?

Why don't you try the `PowerShell` version of the `tee` command?

Here is a [reading](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937(v=wps.620).aspx)

If you are insistent in using only CMD, I think it would be difficult as there is no way (AFAIK) to immediately flush the log buffer to disk.

Comment: MiSAKACHi ~ Yes, actually I wanted to use it in Jenkins, so I didn't want to install any plugins there. Though I can use Powershell there, I will use this. Thanks for the solution :)